# How to Plot Markers on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, c#, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

[image]I'am able to fetch my data from database in json format and currently i can see data in console , So my question is how can i plot the markers from the lat long which i have retrieved using this ajax call.

How can i get marker on function success

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            var pData1 = [];
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ pData1: pData1 });
           // var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "map.aspx/getCityPopulation2",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,

            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                console.log(response.d)
            }
```

Comment: Have you read the Leaflet [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html)?

Comment: Yeah i have read but my ques is how to plot markers by the cordinates which are fetched from database

Comment: Sounds trivial to do… if you need further help, at least show what your response looks like, and _maybe_ someone will code it for you.

Comment: I have edited the question with my console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a loop that iterates through the markers and adds them to the map

A working example is here http://codepen.io/hkadyanji/pen/BLyYYY

```
//select the div that holds the map object
var mymap = document.querySelector("#map")

// ... initialize the leaflet map as expected -> such as adding a tile layer

//a function to add the markers to the map
//you will call this function passing the resulting array from
//the ajax call as the parameter

function addToMap(locationArray){

   //iterates through the array object called from the server
   [].forEach.call(locationArray, function(location){

       var marker = L.marker([location.lat, location.lng]).addTo(mymap);

      //you can even add a custom popup for the individual marker
      //marker.bindPopup("custom pop up content goes here").openPopup();
    }
 }
```